# EF6 code first add migration - where is the 'snapshot of the current code' stored?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I add a migration for my EF6 code first project, I get this message

```
"The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot 
of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to 
calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the 
next migration. If you make additional changes to your 
model that you want to include in this migration, 
then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration AddAssignmentProperty' again."
```

Is there a way to see what this snapshot is, or is it some unreadble blob stored in a secret place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snapshot of your model is stored in the table `_MigrationHistory` in the column `Model` which is a binary blob representation of the Gzipped EDMX description of your model.

However, an EDMX is not something I would consider readable if you are used to code first.